# Populate Pandas Series with list

Tags: python, pandas, list

I would like to populate a `pd.Series()` with a `list`.

I tried doing the following:

```py
series = pd.Series(index=['a','b','c','d'])
series['a'] = 2
series['b'] = [2,3]
```

This is the error that I get. How can I populate the `list` in the `pd.Series`?

```py
 File "C:\Users\Sergej Shteriev\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 940, in setitem
    values[indexer] = value

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the initial dtype is assumed to be float (as the series is filled with NaNs).

```
series.dtype
# dtype('float64')
```

Since lists are only supported by `object` type columns, you'd need to cast before assigning.

```
series = series.astype(object)
series['b'] = [2, 3]
series

a           2   # this is still a float
b      [2, 3]
c         NaN
d         NaN
dtype: object

series.tolist()
# [2.0, [[2, 3]], nan, nan]
```

---

A better suggestion is to declare `series` as an object at the start if that's what you intend stuffing into it.

```
series = pd.Series(index=['a','b','c','d'], dtype=object)
series['a'] = 2
series['b'] = [2, 3]

series
a         2
b    [2, 3]
c       NaN
d       NaN
dtype: object

series.tolist()
# [2, [2, 3], nan, nan]
```

Of course, for performance reasons, I don't condone this. You're better off using python lists -- they're usually faster than object Series.

Comment: Ah okey, I understand now. Thanks a lot!